# Error when deploying Next.js to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, next.js

I get the following error when I deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Does anyone know why it happens?

```
> client@0.1.0 start /var/app/current
> next start -p $PORT

ready - started server on http://localhost:8081
TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
        at NextScript.getPolyfillScripts (/var/app/current/.next/server/static/8Nm58iB3JDC5SQahrWuy9/pages/_document.js:735:26)
        at NextScript.render (/var/app/current/.next/server/static/8Nm58iB3JDC5SQahrWuy9/pages/_document.js:836:75)
        at d (/var/app/current/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:38:231)
        at $a (/var/app/current/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:39:16)
        at a.b.render (/var/app/current/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:44:476)
        at a.b.read (/var/app/current/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:44:18)
        at renderToStaticMarkup (/var/app/current/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:54:462)
        at renderDocument (/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/render.js:3:624)
        at renderToHTML (/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/render.js:50:72)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot of info here to go off of, but I had this exact issue when deploying to an ec2 container and upgrading to Next 9.5.1 fixed it (previously at 9.4.4).